# Program runs as SYSTEM still not able to edit hosts file

Tags: c#, windows, hosts, admin-rights

I'm trying to edit the hosts file while my program is started as "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" with psexec, and I still get `UnauthorizedAccessException`. I thought that SYSTEM should be able to edit hosts file that's why I'm started my program with `psexec -i -d -s myapp.exe`.
So what should I do to be able to edit hosts file?

Comment: What OS is it running on? Windows Server 2008 vs Win8 vs Win7 vs Vista behave differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your hosts file is not marked as read-only. If it is, you will get this exception regardless of current user permissions.

Comment: Yes you're right, first I removed read-only but it didn't work, then I set  the attributes to normal, and now I can edit it. But it is not marked as System file anymore, can it be a problem in the future?

Comment: You can restore file attributes to previous value after you finished editing it. You can use FileSystemInfo.Attributes to read and set them.

Comment: You may need to do a "Demand" within Code Access Security to ensure that the application has elevated permissions.